If there exists $A\subset X$ such that $X$ is equal to the closure of $A$ then $X$ is closed.
QUESTION:
Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. If there exists $A\subset X$ such that $\overline{A}=X$ then $X$ is closed?
MY ATTEMPT:
On one hand, $\overline{A}$ is equal to the smallest closed set containing $A$. So $X$ is equal to a closed set and therefore closed.
However, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$ (the rationals) then $\mathbb{R}=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (under the standard topology), but $\mathbb{R}$ is neither open or closed.
So it appears to me that the statement is true if $X\subset\mathbb{R}$?
BONUS QUESTION (optional):
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $S:\Omega\Rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a correspondence.
Suppose there exists a countable collection of measurable functions $\{f_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $f_j:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n,$ such that for every $\omega\in \Omega$
we have $S(\omega)= \overline{\{f_j(\omega):j\in\mathbb{N}\}}$. Does this imply $S(\omega)=\overline{S(\omega)}$?

I don't think the above question answers OP's questions since that post talks about "why the closure of a set is closed", which is something the OP seems to already know.

How are you defining the closure of a set?  I define it as the intersection of all closed sets containing the given set, so it is definitionally closed.

@lulu That is the definition I'm using. I'm doing all of this to apply a result from Aliprantis and Border, 2006 and that is how they define it.

Right.  But, arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed, so the closure of a set is closed.

Yes, as has been pointed out this question stems from my misunderstanding of $\mathbb{R}$ being open and closed (as opposed to not being open or closed).

The result you state is not only true for $\Bbb R$ but for any topological space $Y$. Your claim that $\Bbb R$ is neither open nor closed is false! Because for any topological space $Y$ (with whatever topology on it), $Y$ is always both open and closed.
In fact as you said, $\overline{A}$ is always a closed subset of the ambient topological space, and hence in your notation, $X$ is always closed if $X=\overline{A}$.
As for your "bonus" question: it's also generally true for any set $S\subseteq Y$ in a topological space $Y$ that $\overline{\overline S} = \overline S$. That is, taking closure twice is the same as taking closure only once. So, whatever hypothesis you have, just because $S(\omega)$ is equal to the closure of some set means
$$ \overline{S(\omega)} = \overline{\overline{\{f_j(\omega):j\in\mathbb{N}\}}} = \overline{\{f_j(\omega):j\in\mathbb{N}\}} = S(\omega)\ . $$
Hope that answers all your questions.

Your first question has a very simple misunderstanding. In $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed. This is true of any topological space: the whole space is both open and closed. In fact, this is an immediate from the axioms of topological spaces.

The fact that any topological space $Y$ is both open and closed is not taken as an axiom. You either postulate that $Y$ is open in $Y$ (OR that it's closed). Then one can derive that $Y$ must also be closed (resp. open) as a consequence of this axiom.

@math-physicist true. But the derivation is immediate. I will edit my answer.

Yes, I was just being extra careful. You're good no problem. The overall answer is still true.

@math-physicist The definition of a topology includes the axioms that both $Y$ and the empty set are open in $Y$. This is essentially the same as postulating that $Y$ is both open and closed in $Y$.
